# What is the meaning of ~ in ~/somefolder?

Tags: folder

I've been told to go to `~/.ssh` and, actually, I did `cd ~/.ssh` and I got into it.

However, I'm wondering: what does the `~` mean in this context?

Comment: also most of the time if you do just "cd" you will land there (~).

Comment: There's actually a bit of historic reason for why `~` has been chosen to represent home directory. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/34196/85039

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`~` = `$HOME` = your home directory

The next commands will change to your home directory `/home/david` if your username is `david`:

```
cd
cd ~
cd $HOME
cd /home/david
cd ~david
```

Comment: "change your home directory" -> "make the home directory the present work directory"

Comment: also, typing `cd` will get you into your homefolder.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use ~username (no slash) to have it lookup the home directory of a user; that is, ~khamer resolves to /home/khamer, whereas ~david would resolve to /home/david regardless of who is typing the command.

Answer (score 0):

If you type:

```
cd ~/
```

and hit TAB, the command should change to the actual path to your home folder. As far as I know, this works with pretty much any command that takes a path as an argument.